# Edit & save dictionary in another python file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, fileupdate

I have 2 python files, file1.py has only 1 dictionary and I would like to read & write to that dictionary from file2.py. Both files are in same directory.

I'm able to read from it using **import file1** but how do I write to that file.

Snippet:

file1.py (nothing additional in file1, apart from following data)

```
dict1 = {
        'a' : 1,      # value is integer
        'b' : '5xy',   # value is string
        'c' : '10xy',
        'd' : '1xy',
        'e' : 10,
        }
```

file2.py

```
    import file1
    import json

    print file1.dict1['a']    #this works fine
    print file1.dict1['b']

    # Now I want to update the value of a & b, something like this:

    dict2 = json.loads(data)
    file1.dict1['a'] = dict2.['some_int']     #int value
    file1.dict1['b'] = dict2.['some_str']     #string value
```

The main reason why I'm using dictionary and not text file, is because the new values to be updated come from a json data and converting it to a dictionary is simpler saving me from string parsing each time I want to update the **dict1**.

Problem is, **When I update the value from dict2, I want those value to be written to dict1 in file1**

Also, the code runs on a Raspberry Pi and I've SSH into it using Ubuntu machine.

Can someone please help me how to do this?

**EDIT:**

1. file1.py could be saved in any other format like .json or .txt. It was just my assumption that saving data as a dictionary in separate file would allow easy update.
2. file1.py has to be a separate file, it is a configuration file so I don't want to merge it to my main file.
3. The **data** for **dict2** mention above comes from socket connection at

`dict2 = json.loads(data)`

4. I want to update the *file1** with the data that comes from socket connection.

Comment: Why don't you write the data to a JSON that is read by both files? As far as I can tell you don't gain anything from having one python file edit another, that just seems really unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to print the dictionary back to the file, you could use something like...

```
outFile = open("file1.py","w")
outFile.writeline("dict1 = " % (str(dict2)))
outFile.close()
```

You might be better off having a json file, then loading the object from and writing the object value back to a file.  You could them manipulate the json object in memory, and serialize it simply.

Z

Comment: Thanks Zaren, as you suggested I stored my data into a json file instead of a dictionary in python file. It made my work a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to save the data from `file1` into a separate `.json` file, then read the `.json` file in your second file. Here is what you can do:

**file1.py**

```
import json
dict1 = {
        'a' : 1,      # value is integer
        'b' : '5xy',   # value is string
        'c' : '10xy',
        'd' : '1xy',
        'e' : 10,
        }
with open("filepath.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(dict1, f)
```

This will dump the dictionary `dict1` into a `json` file which is stored at `filepath.json`.

Then, in your second file:

**file2.py**

```
import json

with open("pathname.json") as f:
    dict1 = json.load(f)

# dict1 = {
        'a' : 1,      # value is integer
        'b' : '5xy',   # value is string
        'c' : '10xy',
        'd' : '1xy',
        'e' : 10,
        }

dict1['a'] = dict2['some_int']     #int value
dict1['b'] = dict2['some_str']     #string value
```

**Note:** This will not change the values in your first file. However, if you need to access the changed values, you can `dump` your data into another `json` file, then load that `json` file again whenever you need the data.

Comment: **I want to change the values in file1** that's what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pickle library to save and load the dictionary https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Here is the basic usage of pickle

```
   1 # Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
   2 import pickle
   3 
   4 favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
   5 
   6 pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )



   1 # Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
   2 import pickle
   3 
   4 favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
   5 # favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

Comment: Thanks James, I looked into pickle, it would have been useful if I had to write a full dictionary all the time. But in my case, I'm won't be sure if I had to write 1 or all values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally as @Zaren suggested, I used a json file instead of dictionary in python file.

Here's what I did:

1. Modified **file1.py** to **file1.json** and store the data with appropriate formatting.
2. From **file2.py**, I opened **file1.json** when needed instead of `import file1` and used `json.dump` & `json.load` on **file1.json**